# How do I read a file from a website without downloading it?

Tags: node.js

I want to read an image file from a link without using .pipe() to then process it with sharp.

I tried getting the response body from:

```
request("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png").on('response',(res)=>{
console.log(res)
})
```

But body always returned undefined.
I didn't want to waste storage on my VPS, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use request with **encoding: null** option. Here is a working example for you.

```
const request = require('request');
const sharp = require('sharp');

const url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_light_color_272x92dp.png';
request.get({ url, encoding: null }, async function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const metadata = await sharp(Buffer.from(body, 'base64')).metadata();
        console.log(metadata);
    }
});
```